# How to return data inside computed property in axios request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a computed property and inside it has axios call. that computed propery i need to loop and show result using `v-for`.

my computed property looks like this.

```
  computed:{
        managers(){
       axios.post('/dispatcher/managers',{
                    'catId':this.catId,
                    'route':this.filters.selectedRoute,
                    'date':this.filters.selectedDate,
                    'manager':this.filters.selectedManager
                        }).then(response=>{
                           return response.data;
                        }).catch(err=>{})
            }

    }
```

When i try to loop `managers` using `v-for` it does not work.

How can i get it to work? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, you should probably use a watcher: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

> In this case, using the watch option allows us to perform an
> asynchronous operation (accessing an API), limit how often we perform
> that operation, and set intermediary states until we get a final
> answer. None of that would be possible with a computed property.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Is it possible to use computed property in this case and get it work?

Comment: Not with standard Vue. But there is a [plugin](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed).

Comment: I don't have a lot of Vue experience, but generally, you should try to follow the best practices established by a framework. You'll likely fall into any number of traps if you try to fight the way they want you to do things. However, +1 for the plugin shared by @StephenThomas. I generally try to avoid such things (unless it's on a path to make it into core), but it looks pretty comprehensive.